# Fullscreen bug using dual monitors on top of each other (GNOME3)

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, display, fullscreen

OK, so I have this weird bug.

I have set up my monitors on top of each other

[image: Display setup]

As you can see the screens aren't totally aligned which is the way I want it.

Now, here's the bug: I can't fullscreen windows on the top monitor. If I fullscreen the window it will only fill the left or right part of the screen (matching the distance from the right edge of the laptop to the right edge of the big screen)
It's like the bottom screen is blocking the middle part of the screen.

This behaviour is not present if I align the screens vertically.
If I drag the corners of the window I can use that part of the screen, it's only when I fullscreen that the problem occurs.

Not sure if this info helps but the only program that I'm able to fullscreen properly is my virtual windows desktop (qemu/virt-manager).

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: > As you can see the screens aren't totally aligned which is the way I want it. The reason that is due to the different resolutions on the monitors. If the dell 24" is 1920x1080 your laptop is probably 1366x768 so AFAIK there is no way to align them perfectly. I am unable to help with the bug and you have probably figured it out by now, however if someone were to help I assume they would need more detail including drivers, hardware, and versions.

Comment: No, the error isn't fixed. I had the same problem in GNOME 3 on Debian. I've switched to XFCE now.
I've been able to figure out that this problem is based on the gnome-panel, but no fix in sight.